# Using create react app, and having ES6 dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uglifyjs, create-react-app

I wrote an npm package `blokus` which use ES6 syntax.

I used `create-react-app` to start a project `web-blokus`, which depends on `blokus`.

I can run `npm start` with no errors, and view my `web-blokus` app in my browser, and it has all the functionality from using the `blokus` package.

The problem is that I get an UglifyJS error when running `npm build`.

```
static/js/main.8afd34e2.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Name expected [./~/blokus/blokus/blokus.js:3,0]
```

It appears there is a known situation with UglifyJS not supporting ES6 dependencies (a few relevant issue threads [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/984) and [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1023)). But I read through these threads as well as a handful of others and I was left pretty confused as to what was planning to be updated and what people were doing as workarounds.

So I wanted to

1) confirm that `create-react-app` will not work out of the box (once you go to `npm build`) if your app has any ES6 dependencies

2) ask what people are doing to fix / bypass the issue (do I have to eject, and swap something in for UglifyJS?)

Since `create-react-app` and ES6 are now so popular, I assume I'm either misunderstanding the limitation, or a standard method of dealing with this limitation is discussed and known.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use ES6 code with create-react-app, or most build systems.

npm packages shouldn't result in ES6 code because of existing tooling, and to a lesser extent, older node versions.

To set up your package, assuming the ES6 code is in the src directory:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-cli babel-preset-latest
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["latest"]
}
```

package.json

```
  "main": "./lib",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --out-dir lib"
  }
```

Then do `npm run build` before publishing.

---

Create a .gitignore with 'lib' in it, and a .npmignore that's empty. The .npmignore needs to exist.

You can run your tests on the src directory (or lib, doesn't much matter).

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. Curious, how does adding `lib` affect 1) unit tests (should they test the src files or the lib files, and if lib then does the test script have to include building first), and 2) .gitignore (should lib folder be in version control, or nah)

Comment: Really? You can't use ES6 in create-react-app? So, I need to do that in order for me to use .map etc? :S

Comment: is this answer still valid?

Comment: To clarify, you can't use ES6 in code that ends up in node_modules. I believe this is still the case